# Python Tkinter, problem with creating unique ListBox on new pages

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter I have step up multiple pages, each page should have a unique `Listbox` that will be populated with unique information.

My problem is the 'listbox' shows the information from my initial page on the other pages. Even if I completely remove the List box from the other pages, the 'Listbox` from my first page still shows up.

This is basically the first time I have used classes with anything, so I am not sure why this isn't working. This is all basically copied form YouTube how to's, and I am trying to bend it to what I need.

```
class Uploader(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) #sets up tk window stuff
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Gr7, Gr8, Gr9): #put new pages on this 
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")    
        self.show_frame(Gr7)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Gr7(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lb = tk.Listbox(width=30, height=15)
        lb.insert('end', *homelist)
        lb.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

class Gr8(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lb1 = tk.Listbox(width=30, height=15)
        lb1.insert('end', *homelist1)
        lb1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


class Gr9(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        lb2 = tk.Listbox(width=30, height=15)
        lb2.insert('end', *homelist2)
        lb2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying which widget should contain the listbox, so all of your listboxes are given the root window as its master. Because you are putting them all in the same row and column, you only see one listbox.

To fix this -- and as a good general rule of thumb -- you should always explicitly provide the master when creating widgets:

```
lb = tk.Listbox(self, width=30, height=15)
```